# Infinite loop in Linq group by

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class `Contact` which contains a `string` field `Name`. Now I have a list of objects of this  class and I want to convert it to a dictionary where key is first letter of name and value is list of contacts which names start with this letter.

Below is my Linq query:

```
var contactsDict = (from c in contacts
                    group c by c.Name.Substring (0, 1) into e
                    select e)
    .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.ToList(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

The problem is that it contains infinite loop somewhere. It also pops out a warning in Xamarin Studio saying that this code never returns.

I cannot see an infinite loop in this code.

Comment: I don't think this is causing the problem, but you don't need the `into e select e` part of the query.

Comment: That is extremely weird but it fixed the problem O.o Thank you!

Comment: I believe this query can be rewritten as `contacts.ToLookup(c => c.Name.Substring(0, 1));` Lookup is not exactly dictionary, but behaves the same way - you get a list of contacts by first letter of name.

Comment: @Alexander, good idea. It's important to note the differences between `ILookup` and `Dictionary` - the big one being that `ILookup` will return an empty sequence if there is no matching key, while `Dictionary` will throw, and it uses `Contains` rather than `ContainsKey` to check for keys.